# Should I install Ubuntu 13.04 64bit?

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit

My computer has a dual core CPU and it's speed is 2 GHz and it has 3 GB RAM the motherboard is an intel DQ965GF. Is 64bit faster and do I have enough RAM? Is it worth upgrading? Will there be better performance from 64 bit/ thanks to all who answer this

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with having 64-bit Ubuntu with 3GB RAM